# SSIS - OLE DB Destination Editor: Add Provider: Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engin

Tags: ssis

When I select from the provider drop down list in the Connection Manager Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine does not exist.

Does anyone know how to have this added as an option that you can select?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm pedantic, the OLE DB Destination Editor will only provide a list of previously defined OLE DB `Connection Managers`.

The question then becomes, how do I get the bits installed to make this an allowed provider. [Download Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)